# Fetching Multiple Records by Record Name

Tags: ios, swift, database, cloudkit, ckrecord

I have an array of record names (or strings) . I want to fetch any record in the public database which has any of these record names. How might I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply something like this...

```
let filter: [String] = [ "String1", "String2", "String3" ]

let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%k IN %@", "record_name", filter)
let query: CKQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "RecordType", predicate: predicate)

CKContainer.default.publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: { @escaping ([CKRecord]?, Error?) -> Void in 
    // Do what you want with your filtered CKRecords ;)
})
```

The `NSPredicate` uses the aggregated operator `IN` in order to filter by the contents of an array. More info at [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891)

Answer (score 3):

Check out `CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [CKRecord.ID])`

you didn't include a code example, but if you have the recordIDs as an array of Strings then:

```
let ids: [String] = [...] // your array of the record names as Strings 
let recordIDs = ids.map { CKRecord.ID(recordName: $0) }
let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (ckRecords, error) in
  ... // do stuff with your records
}
CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

Comment: May you please give an example on how to do stuff with your records? I tried `let recordField1 = ckRecords["recordField1"]` to access them but received the error `No exact matches in call to subscript`. Appreciate the help!

Comment: What specifically do you want to do? I think your question is out of scope from the original question. But note that ckRecords is a dictionary.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordsoperation/1476078-fetchrecordscompletionblock